# Alter or delete user data using Asyncstorage when Uninstall React Native App

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

How to `alter` or `delete` specific application data using `Asyncstorage` when `uninstall` or `update` app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- When you `uninstall` your app by default `Asyncstorage` data will be deleted.
- For `update` thing, you can **store** and **check** current app version at very starting
  of application and if mismatches then do whatever you need.

Comment: If you're just updating the app, does the AsyncStorage data are deleted ?

Comment: no data remains same it wont affect anything while update.

Answer (score 3):

App locally saved data might be backed up on Google Drive on the latest versions of Android. You can disable it either by setting `<android:allowBackup="false">` (true is the default behavior) or by disabling auto backup in your phone's settings.